# Implementing wc in assembly

Tags: c, assembly

I am trying to convert a typical wc C code into intel assembly code. 
The C code is the source, and the aseembly is the one I made. 
Since it doesn't have any function calls, I thought this would work, but it always
end up with iCharCount corrupted and iLineCount staying 0. What could be the problem?

C Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
enum {FALSE, TRUE};
int main(void){
   int iLineCount = 0;
   int iWordCount = 0;
   int iCharCount = 0;
   int iChar;
   int iInWord = FALSE;
   iChar = fgetc(stdin);
   for( ;iChar != EOF; ){
      iCharCount++;

      if (iChar == '\n') iLineCount++;
      if (isspace(iChar)){
         if (iInWord){
            iWordCount++;
            iInWord = FALSE;
         }
      }
      else if (!iInWord) iInWord = TRUE;
      iChar = fgetc(stdin);
   }

   if (iInWord) iWordCount++;
   printf("%7d%8d%8d\n", iLineCount, iWordCount, iCharCount);
   return 0;
}
```

Assembly Code

```
    .file "wc.s"
    .section        .rodata
    .equ TRUE, 1
    .equ FALSE, 0
    .equ SPACE, 32
    .equ LCHANGE, 10
    .equ TAB, 9
    .equ EOF, -1
    .globl main
    .type main, @function
main:
start:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    andl $-16, %esp
    subl $48, %esp
    movl $0, 20(%esp) #int iLineCount = 0
    movl $0, 24(%esp) #int iWordCount
    movl $0, 28(%esp) #int iCharCount
    movl $0, 36(%esp) #int iInWord = FALSE
    movl stdin, %eax
    movl %eax, (%esp)
    call fgetc
    movl %eax, 32(%esp) #iChar = fgetc(stdin)
    cmpl $EOF, 8(%ebp) #Start of for( ;iChar != EOF;)
    je endloop
loop:
    incl 28(%ebp)   #iCharCount++
    cmpl $LCHANGE, 32(%ebp) #if(iChar == '\n')
    jne ecomp1
    incl 20(%esp) #iLineCount++
ecomp1:
    cmpl $LCHANGE, 32(%esp) #if(isspace(iChar) ->'\n'
    je isspace
    cmpl $SPACE, 32(%esp) #-> ' '
    je isspace
    cmpl $TAB, 32(%esp) # -> '\t'
    je isspace
    jmp elsespace
isspace:
    cmpl $TRUE, 36(%esp)    #if(iInWord)
    jne last
    movl $FALSE, 36(%esp) #iInWord = FALSE
    incl 24(%esp)   #iWordCount++
    jmp last
elsespace:
    cmpl $FALSE, 36(%esp)   #if(!InWord)
    jne last
    movl $TRUE, 36(%esp)    #iInWord = TRUE
last:
    movl stdin, %eax
    call fgetc
    movl %eax, 32(%esp)     #iChar = fgetc(stdin)
    cmpl $EOF, 32(%esp)     #Recheck for statement
    jne loop
endloop:
    cmpl $TRUE, 36(%esp)    #if(iInWord)
    jne else
    incl 24(%esp)   #iWordCount++
else:
    movl 28(%esp), %eax
    movl %eax, 12(%esp) #push iCharCount in printf
    movl 24(%esp), %eax
    movl %eax, 8(%esp) #push iWordCount in printf
    movl 20(%ebp), %eax
    movl %eax, 4(%esp) #push iLineCount in printf
    movl $.format, (%esp)
    call printf
    leave
    ret
.format:
    .string "%7d%8d%8d\n"
    .text
```

Comment: Why not step through the code in your debugger to see what the problem is ?

Comment: I tried to use gdb for that, but I was not able to observe each variables in esp stack... Do you have any reference for that?

Comment: To look at a variable on the stack, you need to get the value of the `esp` register, and ask `gdb` to dump memory in that area. Examine the location at the offset you want.

Comment: The problem described is quite clear: assembly conversion of C code does not behave the same way.  `wc`'s behaviour is quite well known and obvious from the C code supplied.  The OP does explain what is unexpected from the assembly version.  This is mostly a question about assembly code.  I did find the bugs: the kind that is obvious when you see it but remains invisible to most casual readers. A good illustration of *Hiding in plain sight*.

Answer (score 1):

There are missing lines in your assembly listing: label `last` is missing as well as the `iChar = fgetc(stdin);` at the end of the loop.

You should simplify your C code. First use the classic idiom:

```
while ((iChar = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) { ... }
```

There is no need for a test in

```
else if (!iInWord) iInWord = TRUE;
```

Nor do you need 2 tests here:

```
  if (isspace(iChar)){
     if (iInWord){
        iWordCount++;
        iInWord = FALSE;
     }
  }
```

You can simplify the loop and the word test this way:

```
while ((iChar = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
    iCharCount++;
    if (iChar == '\n') iLineCount++;
    if (isspace(iChar)) {
        iWordCount += iInWord;
        iInWord = 0;
    } else {
        iInWord = 1;
    }
}
iWordCount += iInWord;
```

The `printf` format is inappropriate: if the counts become too large, the numbers will be glued together.  Use this instead:

```
printf("%7d %7d %7d\n", iLineCount, iWordCount, iCharCount);
```

As for the assembly version, it seems to have been produced by the compiler, then somewhat patched by hand.  You did rewrite the `isspace()` test and you do not test some white space characters such as `'\r'` and `'\f'`.  The test for `'\n'` is redundant, you could jump to `isspace:` after incrementing `iLineCount`.

**EDIT:** The problem with your assembly code is this: You sometimes mistakenly use `%ebp` instead of `%esp` to access local variables.

```
    ...
    cmpl $EOF, 8(%ebp) #Start of for( ;iChar != EOF;)
    ...
loop:
    incl 28(%ebp)   #iCharCount++
    cmpl $LCHANGE, 32(%ebp) #if(iChar == '\n')
    ...
    movl 20(%ebp), %eax
    ...
```

Comment: I am terribly sorry about missing blocks of codes, I editted it

Comment: My goal is to convert the current C code to an Assembly code, therefore I am not able to take your advice about the style of the c code, sorry once more

Comment: @lulamb00: I found your problem, look at the edited answer.